# Get Webflow requestScope value from FacesContext

Tags: java, jsf-2, spring-webflow

I am using SWF (Spring WebFlow) 2.2 and JSF 2.0.4.

In `flow.xml` I am setting the variable into the requestScope of SpringWebFlow.

```
<set name="requestScope.RE_RENDER_TABLE" value="true" type="java.lang.Boolean" />
```

But, I need this variable in the JSF using the `FacesContext`. I tried the following ways, but both returns `null`.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("RE_RENDER_TABLE");
```

How do I get the requestScope variable added in `flow.xml` file in JSF context?

Comment: What exactly does `getRequestMap()` contain? Please also note that SWF tag here stands for ShockWave Flash, not Spring WebFlow. I updated the tags (and the rest, you have had a `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getFacesContext()` which makes obviously no sense).

Comment: First, thanks for updating the Tag.

Return the environment-specific object instance for the current request

Comment: getRequestMap() :- instance for the current request object, whose Request Scope Attributes Map is returned>

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getFacesContext() :- yes, it absolutely male any sense.
But, its never used.

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext() :- This would return ExternalContext, which is used by the JSF API to get the ServletContext, ServletRequest, and ServletResponse objects through the instance of ExternalContext>

Answer (score 0):

In xhtml try

```
 #{requestScope.RE_RENDER_TABLE}
```

or, in backing bean:

```
FacesContext getFacesContext() {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
}

ELContext elc = getFacesContext().getELContext();
ExpressionFactory ef = getFacesContext().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
ef.createValueExpression(elc,"#{requestScope.RE_RENDER_TABLE}",Boolean.class).getValue(elc);
```

Answer (score 0):

or try simple **#{RE_RENDER_TABLE}** (over all scopes).

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be better if you provided some small intuition/explanation of the answer along with the code.